# Bootstrap Carousel does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

None of the carousel's buttons are responsive and whenever clicked don't do anything. The first image of the carousel shows up but I can't move on to the other one. Here is a screenshot

[image]

and here is the HTML code http://pastebin.com/cmtkH9vA
Please help me get over the problem, as I'd like to get the carousel done as fast as I could. Thank you.

Comment: please share your code...what you have tried.

Comment: Not working is a feature: http://shouldiuseacarousel.com :o)

Comment: Riad, I did share the code. It's below the screenshot. In case you still don't see it: http://pastebin.com/cmtkH9vA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I run your code it gives the following error in Firebug:

```
Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery
```

This is because jQuery isn't loaded properly in your code.

You can (quick) fix this by adding http:// or https:// to the jQuery URL.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For using Bootstrap Carousal your HTML should look like and remember bootstrap.min.js uses jQuery so you shold add a reference of jQuery first :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css"></script>
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Menu -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

      <!-- Item 1 -->
    <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/1"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Bootstrap 3 Carousel Layout</h1>
          <p>This is an example layout with carousel that uses the Bootstrap 3 styles.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="http://getbootstrap.com">Learn More</a>
        </p></div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!-- Item 2 -->
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/2"/>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Changes to the Grid</h1>
          <p>Bootstrap 3 still features a 12-column grid, but many of the CSS class names have completely changed.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <!-- Item 3 -->
    <div class="item">
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1500/600/abstract/3" />
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Percentage-based sizing</h1>
          <p>With "mobile-first" there is now only one percentage-based grid.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
  </a>  
</div>


 <script>
        $(function () {
    $('#homeCarousel').carousel({
        interval:2000,
        pause: "false"
    });
    });
  </script>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saikotju/esr3qLrx/)