# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel buttons not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement the bootstrap 3 carousel into my site however the slide buttons for left and right are not working and so are the slide dots. Can anyone spot a problem in my code?

```
<!doctype html> 
<html>
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" scr="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <title>Test page! </title>
</head>


<body>
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="img/deepcleaning1.jpg" alt="deepcleaning">
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="img/deepcleaning2.jpg" alt="deepcleaning2">
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you post a fiddle too

Comment: you could try replace the jquery link with this ```<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>``` there is a chance it is not finding the jquery the way you have it referenced

Comment: check for console errors once!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a similar issue to: [Bootstrap Carousel does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27467349/bootstrap-carousel-does-not-work?rq=1)

The answer there recommends checking for javascript errors, particularly the link to jquery.  It seems that adding http or https to the URL could fix the issue.

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned that for some reason the jquery link was not working... All I did was download the jquery file and linked to it instead of using the API. Works like a charm.

Don't know why the link didn't work for me though...